# How to handle an indefinite number of events?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

So say I have some code that creates an indefinite number of comments in a main section of the page, such as

```
function createcomments(comments) {
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
        var comment = document.createElement("quoteblock");
        comment.innerHTML = comments[i];
        main.appendChild(comment);
        comment.classList.add("comment");
    }
}
```

And every time a visitor to my page hovered over a comment the background would turn red or something:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var comments = document.querySelectorAll(".comment");
    // code for handling .onmouseover and .onmouseout
    // for each element in the array
}
```

How would I do that? I think there is a way to do it with jQuery, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) { comments[i].onmouseover=function() { ... } } or test the event.target in the mouse over on the document level

Comment: Am I missing something, what's `getSelectorAll()`? Google produces nothing that suggests it's a known feature of a library (or JavaScript/ECMAScript). Did you mean [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll)?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

Comment: My bad, yeah it is `querySelectorAll(). Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery there are this two helper functions `delegate()` and `live()`.
They work as nicely described in [this](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/) blog post.

Actually you can attach an eventHandler to a parent element that is than listeing to all mouse events (and other events). Using delegation you then check on the parent elements eventHandler if the event is coming from a specific child.

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

here we add some simple html, but we dont attach to the span element for a click handler, but to the div. in the div eventHandler we then check, what target actually got clicked

```
var divs = document.querySelector("ul");
divs.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
   if (ev.target.tagName === "LI")
       console.log("A list element  (" + ev.target.innerText + ") was clicked");
});
```

The whole reason behind this `delegation` is performance. also, if you remove or add items dynamically, the event handling works as expected without any additional work.

If you dont want to use the whole jQuery for this simple step, I still suggest you use some framework, as it is always better to use community support than reinventing the wheel

try http://craig.is/riding/gators, looks nice :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you use `document.querySelector` for the first element in the array?